# How to lock "Run" button in TeamCity

Tags: teamcity

I made a build in TeamCity which deploys code to live server. As a precaution I want to disable that button "run" can be clicked by mistake.So I want to have an additional level of checking "whether I'm sure" I want to click "run" button. Is it possible to accomplish?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 17):

I don't think there is a way to disable the run button.

An approach I've used is to have a Property which gets passed to the build script which needs to be true for the script to run, it's false or not set then the build script throws an error. Then in the build configuration on the Properties & Environment Variables page I set the property to false. Now whenever I need to run the script I have to use the "**Run custom build**" button (the "`| ...`" bit beside the run button), then I set the value to true before hitting the build button.

Answer (score 5):

Another, easier option, is to add a agent requirement to your build such that only the production server's agent can meet it (e.g. env.COMPUTERNAME equals MyProductionServer01), and then disable the agent with a note about "locking" the production build. This will prevent the build from actually running if you accidentally click the Run button.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot disable the run button but you can set permissions so that people are still able to view the project without the ability to run it (specifically the Run Build role).

As far as the confirmation goes there is nothing built into TeamCity to accomplish this but I do believe it would be possible to write a small plugin to gain this type of functionality.

Plugin Information:

http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD6/Developing+TeamCity+Plugins

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, there is no ability to hide Run button unless the build configuration is placed in a different project, which user has no permission to run builds in.

There is a related [feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-23529) in TeamCity issue tracker.

As to requesting confirmation, there is still no [direct support](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-8284), but since TeamCity 7.0 one may add a parameter with mode "prompt" and this will result in the run custom build dialog popping out on Run button click.

Answer (score 3):

We have solved this by providing double log-ins for our users. The normal user is not having permisson to run dangerous projects, but if the log in as elevated.user they have access to the run button for these projects as well.

So in normal situations there is no risk of running by accident.

Comment: The second benefite here is that we also have the possibility to allow only senior users to be allowed to run these critical projects.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is disable button for run. You can pause the build and run it when you want to deploy to live sever.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I'm aware of. If you have enterprise you could set it up so that there is a special account which has permissions to execute that build. Another workaround would be to make the build look at a specific branch in your SCM repo with restricted permissions, etc. Typically merging to a branch requires a bit of effort so its not as easy as hitting run by accident. Also ensures that someone hitting run won't necessarily grab the latest unstable copy from the trunk or somesuch.

Answer (score 0):

You can now remove the Run button by adding teamcity.ui.runButton.caption parameter with an empty value.

See [this comment](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-23529#focus=Comments-27-3600906.0-0) on YouTrack.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).